# Strange URL requests

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a problem with my website. I will appreciate if someone will help me.
So I have these strange requests, seen inside my google analytics account:

https://oddslot.com/?c=node&n=1036682&i=B00B1Q6PQA&x=Roxy_Girls_7_16_Wave_Break

https://oddslot.com/?a=commercial_finance

My site is completely different than those ending words so the problem is how can I stop showing those kinds of URLs?
I think it`s a htaccess problem but what code should I use there to redirect to home page or showing a 404 not found page ?
Thank you all.

Comment: It will be tricky because they are hitting your domain root and then adding query string parameters, so your server is showing the default file (normally index.html / index.php), making it a valid request, can you see the ip of these requests? do they all use the same IP or various ones?

Comment: I`m not seeing any IPs, only those URLs. It is possible to add some lines to htaccess to prevent showing this kind of strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without query string with the home page, you can use in your htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301]
```

Comment: Ok I understand but what if I have a page like this? https://oddslot.com/tips/?page=2   It should work with those lines ?

Comment: You only have 2 options: 1) Indicate any that you wish to authorize or 2) Indicate any that you wish to refuse. But for now I only blocked the home page. So this is not a problem in your case.

Comment: Done it. Those URLs I was talking about are now redirecting to the home page. Thank you.